# BigQuery with Spark to save into Partitioned Tables

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

When I use BigQuery with Spark ,I wan to special Partitioned Tables.like this:

```
configureBigQueryOutput(hadoopConf, 
            "test", "shade2$20170626",
            "[{'name': 'word', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'word_count', 'type': 'INTEGER'}]");
```

but when i run the program , the error occurs ：

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
>   datasetAndTableString 'test.shade2$20170626'; must match regex
>   '[a-zA-Z0-9_]+.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+'. at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryStrings.parseTableReference(BigQueryStrings.java:55)
>   at
>   com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryConfiguration.configureBigQueryOutput(BigQueryConfiguration.java:238)
>   at
>   com.vsoontech.bi.bq.spark.BqSparkDemo2.configureBigQueryOutput(BqSparkDemo2.java:44)
>   at
>   com.vsoontech.bi.bq.spark.BqSparkDemo2.execute(BqSparkDemo2.java:66)
>   at com.vsoontech.bi.bq.spark.Main.main(Main.java:10)

So，there is anything to solve it ,if i want to special the date partion of the table? thinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in the most recent version of the bigdata-interop library.

See:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/bigquery/BigQueryStrings.java

"$" (the partition delimiter) has been added as a valid character in a table reference.

Comment: Thinks! This solve my problem. The act is i use the old version 0.7.2-hadoop2 for google-connector. When i change to 0.8.0-hadoop2 (confirm  BigQueryStrings contains "$" ).  it works.